# Why does signal.pause() stop sockets from breaking?

Tags: python, sockets, signals, python-multiprocessing

I am working with sockets using Python 3.5 and the `multiprocessing` module and running into an unexpected behavior. My program is essentially a couple of threads running until a certain message is received by the client telling it to stop.

If I execute it like this, I get a `BrokenPipeError` that breaks the program, despite the `while True` loop and the `except` block.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import signal
import traceback
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
from process import Process

def main():
    while True:
        try:
            # a Process has a couple threads
            process = Process()
            listener_pool = Pool(processes=1)
            sender_pool = Pool(processes=1)

            # blocking socket client that runs forever
            listener_pool.apply_async(process.listener_thread.run, ())

            # blocking socket server that runs forever
            sender_pool.apply_async(process.sender_thread.run, ())

            return 0

        except BrokenPipeError:
            traceback.print_exc()

            # closing connections
            process.emitter_thread.socket.close()
            process.listener_thread.socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

However, when I added a `signal.pause()` right before returning, not only the code runs as intended, but also no `BrokenPipeError` is raised at any time.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import signal
import traceback
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
from process import Process

def main():
    while True:
        try:
            # a Process has a couple threads
            process = Process()
            listener_pool = Pool(processes=1)
            sender_pool = Pool(processes=1)

            # blocking socket client that runs forever
            listener_pool.apply_async(process.listener_thread.run, ())

            # blocking socket server that runs forever
            sender_pool.apply_async(process.sender_thread.run, ())
            signal.pause()
            return 0

        except BrokenPipeError:
            traceback.print_exc()

            # closing connections
            process.emitter_thread.socket.close()
            process.listener_thread.socket.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/signal.html#signals-and-threads), signals can only be handled by the main thread, but both sockets are being handled by secondary threads. What does `signal.pause()` do to prevent the sockets from breaking, when they are not even being called in the same context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`apply_async`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply_async), as its name suggests returns immediately. Therefore in the first version of your program, the main thread exits right as it starts the child threads (dummy processes are just [threads using the multiprocessing api](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy)).

Therefore the main thread has exited the `try` block long before the exception happens.

In the second case, `signal.pause()` forces the main thread to wait in the `try` block, where it will catch the exception.

Do note this is a fragile solution though, as receiving *any* signal will make `signal.pause()` resume and the main thread exit.

Comment: By the way it's your design decision, but if you work with python3.5+, going asynchronous is much more convenient than python threads (be it through thread or multiprocessing api).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, then, wouldn't `traceback.print_exc()` warn me that a socket was broken instead of failing silently? I took away some code to make it easier to read, but both threads would at least write critical exceptions to a log file. I even moved `signal.pause();return 0` below the `except` block and I still don't get any `BrokenPipeError`. Does it mean no sockets are failing?

Comment: It probably means they are not failing yes. To be sure, you can try to make one fail on purpose, you should see the exception.

Comment: Just tried. They are not failing, indeed. I played around with replacing `signal.pause() with `time.sleep()` and I believe the main thread, upon exiting, was closing all connections (perhaps as part of garbage collection). Thank you for your help, now I understand what needs to be fixed here.